# How do I change Alt+Enter keyboard shortcut in IntelliJ/Android Studio?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to change <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (*Show the list of available intention actions*) keyboard shortcut in IntelliJ/Android Studio?

I have browsed through `File->Settings->Keymap` and couldn't find it, though I remember that I was changing it before.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You find it in the Keymap settings under

`Other->Show Intention Actions`

[image]

Comment: This is now called 'Show Context Actions'.